# How do I get this json recognised by Google charts

Tags: javascript, json

I've been trying to work out why google charts won't plot this JSON data in a line chart

I've scoured the internet but can't find the answer, so calling on the big guns now ...

From a .CSV file loaded into a PHP array 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Time] => 16:37:36
            [Value] => 27.1
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [Time] => 16:42:05
        [Value] => 27.0
    )
```

etc

Then in JS convert to json format to give me this
var ar = [{"Time":"16:37:36","Value":27.1},{"Time":"16:42:05","Value":27} etc

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Time');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');       
data.addRows(ar);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 200});
```

When I run the script, all I get is a basic graph without any plotted data, just an empty graticule
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your array needs to be changed from:

```
var ar = [{"Time":"16:37:36","Value":27.1},{"Time":"16:42:05","Value":27} etc
```

to (drop the '{', '"Time":' and '"Value":')

```
["16:37:36",27.1],["16:42:05",27] ,etc
```

For your Google LineChart see the example below

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCurveTypes);

function drawCurveTypes() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Time');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Value');

      data.addRows([
        ["16:37:36", 27.1],    ["16:42:05", 27],   ["16:44", 23],  ["16:46", 17.0],   ["16:51", 18],  ["16:54", 9]
      ]);

      var options = {
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Hits'
        },
        series: {
          1: {curveType: 'function'}
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Comment: Thanks Mark, All sorted from your guidance :-)